# How do I create a session variable in DotVVM viewmodel?

Tags: asp.net, session, dotvvm

I am building a site in DotVVM and when I try the following line of code but I get error: NullReferenceException

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add ("Value", Item3);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**DotVVM** is an **OWIN middleware**, so you have to configure OWIN first to enable session. First, you need to declare this method, which turns on ASP.NET session:

```
public static void RequireAspNetSession(IAppBuilder app) {
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        var httpContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);
        httpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        return next();
    });

    // To make sure the above `Use` is in the correct position:
    app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
}
```

Then in the `Startup.cs` file, call it:

```
app.RequireAspNetSession();
```

Then you can use `HttpContext.Current.Session["key"]` to access your session state.

Answer (score 0):

You can save an object in the Session by doing:

```
Session["Value"] = Item3;
```

You can retrieve an object from the Session by doing:

```
object value = Session["Value"];
```

Usually, you need to cast the value to the type you used, so if `Item3` is a string, then you would do:

```
string value = (string)Session["Value"];
```

You can access session variables from your views as well, so you shouldn't need to store it in your viewmodel.

Comment: In classic asp.net yes, but i'm using new asp.net framework dotVVM. I'm wrote it later sorry.

Comment: @TomášJurásek Ah, my bad - I didn't notice the dotvvm tag.